# Google Keep web app's onclick note expansion

Tags: ajax, web2py

I was told that I need to use ajax to do this but I have no idea how to start. I am working on the web2py framework.

First onclick, I would have to retrieve data from the notes database, as the notes are input into a form.
Next, I would have to put this data into a new and improved non-writable text box which spans majority of the screen(as in Google keep)

Can someone give me some pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately [Google Keep](http://keep.google.com/) has no public API for the moment. ([source](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3477))

However permissions checks are enabled on Google authentication dialog ([source](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fmemento%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fclient_channel%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.peopleapi.readwrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Freminders%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Foffers.lmp%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.me&immediate=false&state=permissionRequest&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fblackmenu%2Fauth&response_type=token&include_granted_scopes=true&client_id=494086030851-93vje778kogr9dnfq2hhli2e918p4hha.apps.googleusercontent.com&authuser=0&pageId=none)) thus we can expect the API to be released in the near future.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate it in a simpler way. Thanks for your help.